# MongoDB get root field after $unwind

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I try to learn aggregation concept with nested array.
I have an object like this.

```
    "_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbf8",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "name": "Teacher Name",
    "class": "7",
    "students": [
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbf9","name": "Student-1","avgResult": 36,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbfa","name": "Student-2","avgResult": 55,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbfb","name": "Student-3","avgResult": 44.6,"studentGroup": "B"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbfc","name": "Student-4","avgResult": 83.6,"studentGroup": "C"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbfd","name": "Student-5","avgResult": 37,"studentGroup": "B"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbfe","name": "Student-5","avgResult": 39.6,"studentGroup": "C"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbff","name": "Student-6","avgResult": 37,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc00","name": "Student-7","avgResult": 34.3,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc01","name": "Student-8","avgResult": 47.3,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc02","name": "Student-9","avgResult": 56,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc03","name": "Student-10","avgResult": 49,"studentGroup": "C"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc04","name": "Student-11","avgResult": 34.6,"studentGroup": "B"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc05","name": "Student-12","avgResult": 55.6,"studentGroup": "A"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc06","name": "Student-13","avgResult": 21.6,"studentGroup": "C"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc07","name": "Student-14","avgResult": 82,"studentGroup": "B"},
        {"_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abc08","name": "Student-15","avgResult": 52.6,"studentGroup": "B"}
    ],
```

**I want to get this result** (group by studentGroup and calculate some statistics then return this as "studentStatistics")

```
   "_id": "601c4bb56e018211b02abbf8",
    "name": "Teacher Name",
    "class": "7",
    "studentStatics":[
     {
        "_id": "B",
        "countofgroup": 5,
        "avgofGroup": 50.2,
        "studentsName": [
            "Student-3",
            "Student-5",
            "Student-11",
            "Student-14",
            "Student-15"
       ]
     },
     {
        "_id": "C",
        "countofgroup": 4,
        "avgofGroup": 48.5,
        "studentsName": [
            "Student-4",
            "Student-5",
            "Student-10",
            "Student-13"
       ]
     },
     {
        "_id": "A",
        "countofgroup": 7,
        "avgofGroup": 45.904761904761905,
        "studentsName": [
            "Student-1",
            "Student-2",
            "Student-6",
            "Student-7",
            "Student-8",
            "Student-9",
            "Student-12"
        ]
      }
     ]
```

For this I create this aggregation

```
this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("601c4bb56e018211b02abbf8"),
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$students",
    },
    {
          $group: {
            _id: "$students.studentGroup",
            countofgroup: { $sum: 1 },
            avgofGroup: { $avg: "$students.avgResult" },
            studentsName: { $push: "$students.name" },
          },
    },
  ]);
```

This returns me "studentStatistics". But how can I get teacher name and class?

**EDIT**

If I use **$first** operation for teacher name like this

```
this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("601c4bb56e018211b02abbf8"),
        isDeleted: false,
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$students",
    },
    {
          $group: {
            _id: "$students.studentGroup",
            doc:{$first:"$name"},
            countofgroup: { $sum: 1 },
            avgofGroup: { $avg: "$students.avgResult" },
            studentsName: { $push: "$students.name" },
          },
    },
  ]);
```

It returns teacher name for every group element

```
[
    {
        "_id": "A",
        "doc": "Teacher Name",
        "countofgroup": 7,
        "avgofGroup": 45.904761904761905,
        "studentsName": [
         ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "B",
        "doc": "Teacher Name",
        "countofgroup": 5,
        "avgofGroup": 50.2,
        "studentsName": [
         ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "C",
        "doc": "Teacher Name",
        "countofgroup": 4,
        "avgofGroup": 48.5,
        "studentsName": [
          ...
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Try the [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator.

Comment: @prasad_ if I use $first like this **doc:{$first:"$name"}**, teacher name returns for every group

Comment: But I try to get result with this order {teacherName - class - studentStatistics[Array]}

Comment: You always have the top-level document after rewind. One copy per item in the array. You will lose it after the first $group stage tho. You can carry the whole document using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT

Comment: @AlexBlex, I don't want to duplicate root element (**teacher name** for this example) for every item during $group operation.

Comment: You have to. How you gonna do the second $group otherwise?

Comment: I edited question and add $first method. But with this method, I am using the "teacher name" a few times. Does this increase the file size or the amount of RAM used?

Comment: @AlexBlex I found a solution, after I learned $facet aggregation

Comment: Nice one. I would only mention it works only if the previous stage ($match) returns no more than 1 document. It perfectly fits into your usecase but may be a bit confusing/misleading for other learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
{
  $unwind: "$students"
},     
{       
  $group: {
      _id: "$students.studentGroup",
      countofgroup: { $sum: 1 },
      avgofGroup: { $avg: "$students.avgResult" },
      studentsName: { $push: "$students.name" },
      doc: { $first: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", class: "$class" } }
  
},
{
  $group: { 
      _id: "$doc", studentStatistics: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
  }
},
{     
  $addFields: {
      "studentStatistics.doc": "$$REMOVE",
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: "$_id.name",
      class: "$_id.class",
  }
}
]).pretty()
```

This is the aggregation which will give the result as you are expecting. Note the second group stage and the final `$addFields` stages used to transform the pipeline data.

Comment: I found a solution, after I learned $facet aggregation

Answer (score 1):

After some tutorials, I find another way with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

> Input documents are passed to the [$facet](https://medium.com/@aviksingha2017/a-different-approach-towards-mongodb-facet-eb65bbddd090) stage only once. $facet enables various aggregations on the same set of input documents, without needing to retrieve the input documents multiple times.

```
    this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("601c4bb56e018211b02abbf8"),
      },
    },
    {
      $facet:{
        //Get teacher name and class from root object
        "teacherInfo":[
          {
            $project: {
              "name":1,
              "class":1
            }
          },
        ],
        //group and calculate student statistics
        "studentStatistics":[
          {$unwind: "$students"},
          {$group: {
            _id: "$students.studentGroup",
            countofgroup: { $sum: 1 },
            avgofGroup: { $avg: "$students.avgResult" },
            studentsName: { $push: "$students.name" },
          }}
        ]
      }
    },
   {
     $project: {
       // return only necessary parts
       _id:{$first:"$teacherInfo._id"},
       name:{$first:"$teacherInfo.name"},
       class:{$first:"$teacherInfo.class"},
       studentStatistics:1
     }
   }
  ]);
```

Comment: The `$first` operator you had used in the _last_ project stage is available from MongoDB v4.4.